# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException... But why?

Tags: android, arraylist, progress-bar

After 3 hours of try i decided to ask here and see if someone can provide me a solution for this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4

Here is my code.

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

--------------------

    status.setText(getString(R.string.init));

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    final Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll(); //4 prefs atm inside.

    final ArrayList<String> props = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (keys != null) {
        for(final Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            props.add(entry.getKey());
            values.add(entry.getValue().toString());
        }

        final int total = props.size();
        progressBar.setMax(total);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < total) {

                    progressStatus += 1;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            if (props.get(progressStatus) != null) {
                                writeProps(props.get(progressStatus), values.get(progressStatus));
                                status.setText(getString(R.string.writing) + ": " + props.get(progressStatus));
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } while (progressStatus == total) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            progressStatus = total + 1;

                            myVoidOnFinish();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

I get the stuck here:

```
writeProps(props.get(progressStatus), values.get(progressStatus));
status.setText(getString(R.string.writing) + ": " + props.get(progressStatus));
```

Comment: hi you are getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4, it means index should have value with 0 to 3 only , check for that please.

Comment: increment `progressStatus` after getting value from Map because if Map size is 4 then currently `progressStatus` value is 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is here

```
while (progressStatus < total) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
}
```

check value of your progress status it should be not greater than 3 while in you code it is 4 in last while index is only from 0 to 3. please set value of your progress status accordingly.

try this

```
 while (progressStatus < total-1) {
                        progressStatus += 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting the progressstatus value like following

```
 final int total = props.size();
 progressBar.setMax(total);
```

and you in the following line you are trying to get values of props ase

```
writeProps(props.get(progressStatus), values.get(progressStatus));
```

see that for the total size of 4 your progressStatus will be 4. But the maximum index of props and values will be 3. So here is the problem

you can set the value to 1 less than the size like

```
 final int total = props.size() - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using one extra index as you can use maximum up to 3. So please start it form zero and  use less then check instead of less then equal to.